# How to change german umlauts to get friendly URL?

Tags: php, url

I have problem, my friendly URL should something like this:

```
$word = 'my-word-äöß';
```

But it seems German umlauts cannot be in URL. Is there any way to put them there, but without converting them ?

```
$notWantedResult = 'Your-word-%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%9F'
```

This is with URL encode, but it is dirty. :(

Comment: is this `my-word-äöß` your expected output from `Your-word-%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%9F`?

Comment: depends what you want to use it for; `url_encode` is there for a reason. but there are domain names with special characters. and another encoding: http://idn-encoding.online-domain-tools.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They german umlauts cannot be in URL, but my suggestion is to use their respective digraphs.

```
$word = 'Your-word-äöß'

$german = array(
            "ä"=>"ae",
            "ö"=>"oe",
            "ß"=>"ss",
            "ü"=>"ue",
            "æ"=>"ae",
            "ø"=>"oe",
            "å"=>"aa",
            "é"=>"e",
            "è"=>"e"
        );

        $friendlyLink = str_replace(array_keys($german), 
                                      array_values($german), 
                                          $word);
```

Comment: Be aware that upper case characters "Ä" => "Ae" etc. are missing in this list.

Comment: german umlauts are: ä, ö, ü. german but no umlaut: ß. not german: æ å é è

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have special characters in your urls, but you can transform any string to be url-compliant.
An eszett (ß) can be transformed to `ss`, which is valid in the german language ([see Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Gro.C3.9Fschreibweise_mit_Ersetzung_von_.C3.9F_durch_SS))

Making replacements for each character is a pain in the ass, and leads to bugs because you'll eventually miss something, leading to a non-compliant url.

I made a function which I have tested against several character sets, and it seems to go well : [check the function seoUrl in this file](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/helpers/blob/master/src/seo.php).

Here's what it does, line per line :

- `$str = preg_replace('#[^\\p{L}\d]+#u', '-', $str);` replaces every character which isn't an unicode character, into a dash.
- `$str = trim($str, '-');` deletes the first and last characters, if they are dashes
- `$str = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);` converts the string to ASCII (character set without accents). The `//TRANSLIT` option means it will convert to the nearest available match, converting special characters to the correct, url-compliant version (I already tried with eszetts and umlauts)
- `$str = strtolower($str);` converts the string to lowercase
- `$str = preg_replace('#[^-\w]+#', '', $str);` deletes any remaining character, in case something was skipped by the other functions.

The function can be tested here : http://tests.brillault.fr/fonctions/string_to_url.php, it converts `my-word-äöß` to `my-word-aoss`.

Comment: The result should be `my-word-aeoess` to be correct. There are also versions for ä, ö, ü which use two ascii letters: ae, oe, ue.